# What's the difference between equality and equivalence of recursive functions?

Tags: logic, computer-science, computability

Equivalence: They agree everywhere where both are defined and one is undefined where ever the other one is.

Comment: I would say they are the same notion - have you encountered them being used differently?

Comment: See [Recursive function : Definition : Strong equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-recursive_function#Definition)

Comment: But why do theyou define Equality?  Isn't it just the usual Notion?

Comment: The "natural" def of *equality* between *functions* would be : $f(n)=g(n)$ for every $n$. But what happens when the two have not the same dom of definition ? Recursive functins are not *total* (i.e. not everywhere defined) and thus the above def must be adapted.